# How to get single value from stdClass Object

Tags: php, oop

I have this standard class object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [access_token] => EAAYX7VzZCIcABAGCnZADQJZBhXvaJ5eIJ34mNyIKLnFpbInEEZBJJJjjYunzsIBidrZARbZCUr68L66RVoiIgkcj9NW4Ssl1X7
    [token_type] => bearer
    [expires_in] => 5162059
)
```

I want to get value of `access_token`:
 `EAAYX7VzZCIcABAGCnZADQJZBhXvaJ5eIJ34mNyIKLnFpbInEEZBJJJjjYunzsIBidrZARbZCUr68L66RVoiIgkcj9NW4Ssl1X7`

Comment: `$object->access_token` should work in this case, where `$object` is an instance of `stdClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do: `$obj->access_token`

Or you can turn it into an array:

```
$array = get_object_vars($obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo $response->access_token;` where `$response` is your object.

Comment: Please take a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer to provide more information. It's fine and dandy to just answer with some code that will probably work, but its even better to provide information about *WHY* and *HOW*that code solves the problem,